# Connect to a Method/Function on close of QTextEdit in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

How can I connect to a function on close of QTextEdit widget Window?

My Code:

```
self.textBox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
self.textBox.setWindowTitle('Editor')
self.textBox.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 500)
self.textBox.show()
self.textBox.???.connect(self.someFunc)   #????
```

If I do

```
self.textBox.close().connect(self.someFunc)
```

It closes immediately and says

`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'connect'`

If I do

```
self.textBox.closeEvent(self.someFunc)
```

It says

`TypeError: QTextEdit.closeEvent(self.someFunc): argument 1 has unexpected type 'method'`

How can I solve this?

Comment: What action do you mean to close?

Comment: Or do you mean closing the widget that contains it?

Comment: This is a text editor that I implemented and is opened from my menubar in mainwindow, it opens like a new window, so when the editor opens and types something to the window then closes the editor(QTextEdit) window then I need the close event to be connected to a function.

Comment: * So when the user opens and types something to the window and then closes it

Comment: I personally dislike monkey-patching, but `self.textBox.closeEvent = self.someFunc` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the most elegant way but it works, the other way is to inherit from QTextEdit and overwrite the closeEvent method by issuing a signal.

Use:

```
    self.textBox = QTextEdit()
    self.textBox.setWindowTitle('Editor')
    self.textBox.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 500)
    self.textBox.show()
    self.textBox.closeEvent = self.function

def function(self, e):
    print("test")
```